# Doing depth4 and breadth4 search using gremlin python

Tags: python-3.x, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to do a depth-4 and breadth-4 query to a Neptune database to collect a subgraph (to obtain all edges and vertices from this subgraph) using gremlin-python. I want first start at a given vertex, expand outward by selecting the given vertex's top 4 weighted outward edges. Then, I repeat the same process for the 4 news nodes again. I want to repeat this outward query process 4 times in total.

I have tried using the following code:

```
g.V('123').repeat(__.outE().order().by("weight",Order.decr).inV().limit(4)).times(4).toList()
```

However, I was returned an empty list. I can't understand why, as I've also tried

```
g.V('123').repeat(__.out().limit(4)).times(4).toList()
```

And I was able to get some vertices (but not what I wanted, because they are not vertices from top weighted edges).

Is there a better way for me to query this Depth-4 and Breadth-4 subgraph? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, your query looks right from a syntax perspective. Perhaps it is a bug in Neptune? In TinkerGraph, I seem to get the same result with and without `order()` step using some sample data. If you could provide a sample script that generates some data where the problem happens and it could be reproduced in TinkerGraph that would be helpful in solving the problem.

The only thing I can imagine is that when you `order()` the edges returned don't go to depth 4 so given the way you've written it, nothing is emitted. Note that I can demonstrate that as follows:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().repeat(outE().order().by('weight').inV()).times(2)
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
gremlin> g.V().repeat(outE().order().by('weight').inV()).times(3)
gremlin>
```

Perhaps you need to `emit()` to help see what's going on?

```
gremlin> g.V().repeat(outE().order().by('weight').inV()).emit().times(3)
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
```